# Eclipse Juno Metrics Plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, metrics

What eclipse metrics plugins exist for the JUNO release of eclipse? I have tried a few general purpose metrics plugins but non of them has functioned properly with the JUNO release of eclipse. 
Almost forgot, we are using Java as programming language.

I want metrics like cyclomatic-complexity, lines of code, method length, parameter excess and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the following, which work fine on Juno:

- [checkstyle](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/): code style, including method length and others
- [checkstyle](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) again: duplicate code detection
- [checkstyle](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) again: Cyclomatic Complexity
- [cobertura](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ecobertura#.UK49jCHA-xs): for test coverage
- [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html#d0e1647): potential pitfalls in your code
- [Google Plugin for eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/) google's own code quality tools including test generation

I suppose you are not looking for profilers, but if you are, consider the (newly resurrected?) [TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/)

Comment: With findbugs, I could not get the 2.0.1 release to run with Juno - the checks run fine, but the results are not reported to the respective views properly. You should try the 2.0.2 beta, it works fine with my system.

Comment: With CheckStyle, you can also define Metrics like "maximum Cyclomatic Complexity allowed" and configure it to show warnings if a method's CC is too high. Other complexity metrics are supported as well.

Comment: I got both Checkstyle and Findbugs working, but I couldn't find the simple metric:  Line of Code.  Any ideas?

Comment: @nissemand haven't used that one, sorry. I simply run cloc from the linux command line

Answer (score 0):

You may also chek the plug-in for Eclipse called "Metrics". It's and old one but it seems to work fine.

http://metrics.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I downvoted this, because it actually does not even remotely answer the question. Yes - this is a plugin, but the former plugin (metrics) does not work with Eclipse > 3.5 and even metrics2 does not seem to want to work with Eclipse 4+. I'll remove this downvote if you could provide some proof, that you can actually enable metrics with this plugin on a project (right-click project -> properties -> metrics -> "enable metrics"). In my case sadly I don't see "metrics" in that properties box.

Answer (score 0):

I found the https://github.com/leonardobsjr/metrics3 source code work fine with eclipse 4.5 :)

You need compile and export  the plugins for yourself.

Or you can use my updatesite:
 https://github.com/qxo/eclipse-metrics-plugin/raw/master/updatesite/

from:
https://github.com/qxo/eclipse-metrics-plugin

For Now (1.3.9) You must in "Java Perspective" for enable metrics with this plugin on a project (right-click project -> properties -> metrics -> "enable metrics").