# Tool like metric_fu or codeclimate.com for Clojure

Tags: clojure, metrics

Are there any tools for Clojure that are similar to Ruby's http://www.codeclimate.com or metric_fu? Something which does automated code review to produce quality metrics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clojure code static analysis tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722641/clojure-code-static-analysis-tools)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of tools such as the metric_fu or codeclimate.com you mentioned for Clojure.

However, there is [kibit](https://github.com/jonase/kibit/) which is "a static code analyzer for Clojure which uses core.logic to search for patterns of code for which there might exist a more idiomatic function or macro".

Also, if you are using [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) for Clojure development, there are a rich number of [plug-ins](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Plugins), some of which relate to code-quality or code visualization and introspection: for example, [lein-bikeshed](https://github.com/dakrone/lein-bikeshed), [lein-vanity](https://github.com/dgtized/lein-vanity), and [lein-clique](https://github.com/Hendekagon/lein-clique).

In addition, if you develop on Eclipse with the [CounterClockwise](https://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/), you may try some of the Java code metric plug-ins to see if they can give you any useful reports for Clojure (note: this may be limited to lines of code if anything). Here is a recent post on [Eclipse plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515260/eclipse-juno-metrics-plugins) for the Juno version of Eclipse related to code metrics.